# how can we call details from database based on id and it should call for every ID without repeating same details of previous ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

```
<?php
$get_cats = "select * from form";
$run_cats = mysqli_query($conn, $get_cats);
if (!$run_cats) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
  exit();
}
while($cats_row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){       
 $cat_id = $cats_row['phone_number'];
 $cat_title = $cats_row['full_name'];
 $user_id = $cats_row['user_id'];
```

//   $post_image = $row_posts['course_choose'];
                        echo "
                        
                        
                            //This is ICON in home and when I click this I will get slider with the ID details but when I create next ID using PHP from FORM but still am able to see the same details of previous ID

```
                    <h2 class='margin_top_large'>$cat_id</h2>
                    <p>$cat_title</p>
                    </div>
                    </li>";   
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: You have to use where clause in your sql query and pass the id value as parameter in the query to database to fetch record for that id.
select * from form where id = $id

Comment: I dont want to pass id by default when I insert details into the database, from that ID it should take

Comment: ok, So cat_id is identity column in your database?

Comment: user_id is my identity column in DB

Comment: then try select * from form where user_id = @@IDENTITY

Comment: @@IDENTITY here what should I replace

Comment: If I give ID value then I am getting that particular details but I want to get automatically after every registration

Comment: help me out from this

Comment: Need more info. Can you please elaborate more or put screenshot in your post?

Comment: Welcome! Enjoy Coding! !!